# How to fix error "Error mapping types" in AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper, ef-core-6.0

I have these two classes which were reverse engineered (scaffolded) with EF Core:

```
public partial class TblA
{
    public TblA()
    {
        TblBs = new HashSet<TblB>();
    }

    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<TblB> TblBs { get; set; }
}

public partial class TblB
{
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual TblA A { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I am trying to use AutoMapper to map an object of class `TblA` into an object of class `A`. This is how class A is defined in my project:

```
public class A
{
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is how my map is defined:

```
CreateMap<TblA, A>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Bs, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TblBs))
    .ReverseMap()
```

In my project, I am creating an object of class `TblA` which I then add to the database via  `AddAsync()` and `SaveChangesAsync()`. Then, I try to map this object to class `A` via `Map<A>(entity)` where `entity` is the object which I also passed to `AddAsync()`.
Right after calling `Map<A>(entity)`, I get this error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

      Mapping types:
      TblA -> A
      <namespace>.TblA -> <namespace>.A

      Type Map configuration:
      TblA -> A
      <namespace>.TblA -> <namespace>.A

      Destination Member:
      Bs

       ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

      Mapping types:
      TblB -> B
      <namespace>.TblB -> <namespace>.B

      Type Map configuration:
      TblB -> B
      <namespace>.TblB -> <namespace>.B

      Destination Member:
      TenantId
       ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        at lambda_method734....
```

I have thoroughly inspected the object before mapping it and the TenantId is set just fine to a valid string value. Therefore, I do not understand where this error is coming from because the `TenantId` is not null. What could be the problem here?

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: You probably need to initialize `Bs` in the public constructor for `A`.

Comment: @Mr.T `Bs` is not only initialized but it even contains items at the point of time when I am attempting to map the object via AutoMapper. This entire error message just does not seem to make any sense because there is no null attribute in the object which I am trying to map at all. I even use the exact same mapping profile somewhere else in my project where I am mapping a collection of `TblA` and it is working just fine there.

Comment: @Mr.T I think I missunderstood your answer. I now added the initialization of `Bs` to my code in class `A` but sadly I am still getting the same error. Is there no better way to actually debug what is going on here? I basically have to guess what might be wrong but I have no way to actually figure it out.

Comment: At this point, we really need to see a full repro that demonstrates the error you're getting.

Comment: Needs a more complete description. `CreateMap<TblB, B>` was not included.